# Collection of Anonymous Types using a datagrid with converter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to use a converter to return `.ToList()` of a collection anonymous types bound to the `Itemssource` of a `Datagrid`?

I have tried this:

//converter

```
 class AnonymousTypeToListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((ObservableCollection<Object>)value).ToList();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

//Datagrid Declaration in xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionData, Converter={StaticResource anonConverter}}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

This doesn't seem to work - the `Converter` gets called but my `Datagrid` is blank:

[image]

My reason for this is because `Datagrid` doesn't like anonymous types...as defined [here](http://www.jaider.net/archives/287-binding-a-datagrid-to-a-linq-anonymous-type/) but I don't think this approach really works for us using an MVVM approach...

Comment: Your `DataGrid` is *not* blank... it has items... one for each line you see. It's just that the `Binding`s (if you have any) are not working. But why would you want to change a correct `ObservableCollection` to an incorrect `List` anyway?

Comment: The bindings are working...if I debug the application and set a breakpoint I can see that the value of `SelectionData` in the XAML. This has something to do with `SelectionData` being `ObservableCollection<object>` - `Datagrid` wont generate the columns...

Comment: the reason I want to change it is due to some research that I found - there is a link that shows binding to datagrids to linq anonymous types and they suggest you do `.ToList()` - this link is in the question in the last sentence. This may give a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Calling `ToList` is just one way to get `LinQ` to generate a concrete collection from the `IEnumerable`... they could just as well have called this: `DataContext = new ObservableCollection(list.Select(v => new { id = v, name = "name " + v }));` which shows another way. The `List` is *not* really part of that example.

Comment: he mentioned that using the `IEnumerable` without calling `ToList` doesn't work (the very last sentence)...If I do an `ObservableCollection<Location>` (`Location` is some table in my database) my rows auto generate correctly...its only with using `ObservableCollection<object>` that my rows do not show up correctly. Is there a different approach or what could be wrong?

Comment: The answer is no it is not possible

Comment: @devhedgehog more of a reason would be nice

Comment: I posted you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects with an anonymous type are internal. You can bind to properties of anonymous types only when running in full trust.

In general, Internet applications should be restricted from having direct access to critical system resources, to prevent malicious damage. By default, HTML and client-side scripting languages are not able to access critical system resources. Because Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) browser-hosted applications can be launched from the browser, they should conform to a similar set of restrictions. To enforce these restrictions, WPF relies on both Code Access Security (CAS) and ClickOnce.

To cut the story short, WPF runs with partial trusted security and therefore Binding doesn't work with anonymous types by default.

However I bet there are "workarounds" on the internet. :)

Answer (score 0):

The comments are so hard to read, so I'll continue in an answer.

What he meant to say was that he could not use an `IEnumerable` as the `DataContext` and so he *chose* the option to call `ToList()` to turn it into a `List`. As I showed you in my last comment, he could just as easily have passed the `IEnumerable` into the `ObservableCollection<T>` constructor:

```
DataContext = new ObservableCollection(
    list.Select(v => new { id = v, name = "name " + v }));
```

There's no point in you casting your `ObservableCollection<Location>` into an `ObservableCollection<Object>` like you are doing in your `Converter`. I still don't get what it's for anyway, but you'd be better off doing this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<Location>((ObservableCollection<Location>)value);
}
```

Of course, there's no point in casting an `ObservableCollection<Location>` into an `ObservableCollection<Location>` and then passing it into a new `ObservableCollection<Location>` but I'm guessing that you'll actually be doing something else in there.

If you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve with your `Converter`, then maybe you'd get some better answers?

Comment: The whole point of this is that I am using one grid...I have one observable collection bound to that one grid. However, I have multiple queries that will fill the `ObservableCollection` hence...the `ObservableCollection<object>` in my testing I used `ObservableCollection<Location>` and it worked. However, I still need to bind an `ObservableCollection<object>` and it does not work. I thought maybe using the converter that I could get a concrete type to bind for the binding. So I may return Locations for one thing or I may return Machines by using the generic `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Dude, just use one view model for each view and your life will be so much simpler.